# Auto layout, are layout guide sizes proportional, per device?

Tags: storyboard, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode7

I'm having trouble getting my views to look good on different iPads with spacing from the sides of the screen. On iPad pro the spacing isn't enough, but on other iPads it looks fine.

I'm using constraint constant values, I'm not using the layout guides.

I'm just wondering if the size of the layout guides is proportional, or is it a fixed size? as i say constant values don't work for me when comparing different iPads.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this video from learning auto layout and how to constrain for all screen size

[Using Auto Layout for Various Screen Sizes](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/implementing-designs-for-iphone/using-auto-layout-and-managing-the-keyboard/using-auto-layout-for-various-screen-sizes)

you can also refer this tutorial

[Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS 9](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

i'll keep updating if i find something else :)

If you are using size class this video might help you 
[How-To : Auto Layout With Multiple Controls In Xcode 6 and iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk)

Comment: I have used sizing classes but the iPad pro spacing is different to other iPads.

Comment: if you are using sizing class this video might help you...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk